# Google search results site map?

Tags: seo, google-search

I was wondering how to achieve the following when searching for my website on Google. I've tried searching around for it but I'm not sure what the exact term is so I haven't gotten anywhere.

Basically, when my website is searched in Google, I'd like the subpages to be indexed like shown in the image below, instead of coming up as another result. Is this possible or is it something that Google does for you?

Take a look at this screenshot:

[image: Google Search screenshot of two search results]

Comment: This is controlled through an automatic process by Google. I don't think you can influence it .

Comment: @TwentyGotoTen is right. The only thing you can influence is asking Google to _remove_ one of the links, through webmaster tools. Make your site interesting, easily crawlable, with well defined sections, and if you can put your site in a top position for an interesting keyword, Google might add multiple links to your website snippet.

Comment: For reference, this is called Sitelinks: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming.

Comment: Asking how search engines will display/rank/parse your site is off topic

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. In this case the question has already been asked and answered there: [What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/503/what-are-the-most-important-things-i-need-to-do-to-encourage-google-sitelinks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google calls them [**sitelinks**](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en).

You can’t enforce them currently:

> We only show sitelinks for results when we think they'll be useful to the user. If the structure of your site doesn't allow our algorithms to find good sitelinks, or we don't think that the sitelinks for your site are relevant for the user's query, we won't show them.
>
> At the moment, sitelinks are automated.

---

For encouraging Google to display them for your site, see the question on Webmasters SE:

[What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/503/17633)

They also have a ["sitelinks" tag](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sitelinks).