# Google microformating and navigation

Tags: navigation, markup, google-search, microformats

i would like to see my website in Google search something like this http://rghost.ru/53917891/image.png (Yahoo)

I really love this additional navigation right from the searching page. 
How can i do this? Is it microformat markup? 
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Search Results Site Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225000/google-search-results-site-map)

Comment: they are related, but not the same

Answer (score 0):

follow the instructions at schema.org, microformats.org, microformats wiki, or developers.google.com, that show you exactly how to mark up certain information, which will then be deemed relevant, and used in serps.

the big three u.s. search engines all utilize different technologies, however they did create schema.org, so you're going to get more features tied directly the platform, which in this case are the search engines. which breaks my heart to say, because microformats are the original semantic web, and are so easy to implement.

not clear on which part(s) exactly, but i do know that google search is tied into g+, so you'll have to make an account there, and then follow their instructions for proving who you are, etc.

not sure if bing requires that...i did try to validate some schema markup specifically for bing with their validator, but they require you to join to use (which is ridiculous) so i decided i could careless how my work performs in bing searches.

yahoo! and yandax may already be doing similar differentiations to tie you in as well, i'm just not really paying attention as much as i used to.

go to http://microformats.org
look up how to implement hcard in your markup, and probably haddress, as well as anything else that is particular to you and your site. once you're "done", make sure it works by validating it....use the microformats validator, not the w3c's.
once it passes, sit back and watch the bots gulp down your tasty semantics.

Answer (score 0):

This happens automatically, you don't have to implement any markup and you have no say on which links show up.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en