# In a google search result, how do links show up beneath a result

Tags: seo, sitemap

I have a sitemap ready already done.

How do I get google results to show a set of links beneath the link?

[image]

I understand that google generates sitelinks by itself, which in turn cause these type of results to show:

[image]

Is there a difference between the first image and the second? are they both sitelinks auto-generated by google?

If not, what's the difference between the first image and the second?

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Search Results Site Map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225000/google-search-results-site-map)

Answer (score 0):

Google adds them if it thinks your site is big enough or popular enough to warrant them. So unfortunately you can't add code to your site to cause these to display.

Google also doesn't allow you to choose the links if it does display them. You can ask them not to display certain links here in Google Search Console (aka Google Webmaster tools) if you've registered your site there but not which ones to display there. How it decides which ones to display is not publically stated but you can probably influence them with a combination of site structure, common links on all pages and which pages are most popular on your site.

The difference between the two is the first one is a generic search (mma) which this site shows for and the second is a specific or band search (mma fighting) which exactly matches this specific site and/or brand.