# Tree search result does not appear on Google

Tags: html, seo, google-crawlers

I am not really sure if this is a programming-related SEO question or not, so let me know.

I made a one pager in HTML5 with php and JS. Nothing weird with it, it works as desired. I used a very structured code. I provide meta name="viewport", meta name="description", meta name="keywords", meta name="author", meta charset="utf-8", html lang="de", a `<title>`, a header for the navigation and all the one pager links link to it's own `<section>`. Every `<section>` has a `<h1>` for a title and a `<h2>` for a subtitle. Every other text is inside of `<p>` marks and all links and images have both title and alt. I also use a `<footer>` at the bottom.

According to Dreamweaver, there are no errors in the code, everything should be OK. I also have uploaded a xml sitemap to the root. I also registered the website on the Google Webmaster tools.

Despite all this, when I search my site on Google, whether it is on google.com or google ad preview tool, I only get a simple result and not a tree with all the links.

Am I forgetting something? Is the code structure wrong? Any other suggestions why this is not happening?

Comment: Is this what you mean by "tree search": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207467/in-a-google-search-result-how-do-links-show-up-beneath-a-result/

Comment: Yes it is! Thanks very much! :)