# schema.org: SiteNavigationElement with multiple elements

Tags: navigation, schema.org, microdata

I am trying to implement schema.org microdata for my menu navigation.
This navigation will look similar to this:

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Name1</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Name2</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span>Name3</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

I want to make use of `SiteNavigationElement`, unfortunately all I could find where examples with no clear answer of how to make use of multiple elements.

Does anybody know for sure, how to use `SiteNavigationElement` on multiple elements?

**UPDATE:**

This is my original menu structure I came up with after reading all answers in the *duplicate link*:

```html
<nav class="menu" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
    <ul class="main-menu" role="menubar">
        <li class="main-menu">Home</li>
        <li class="parent">
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li><a itemprop="url" role="menuitem" href="index.php"><span itemprop="name">Home</span></a></li>
                <li><a itemprop="url" role="menuitem" href="tricks.php"><span itemprop="name">Tricks</span></a></li>
                <li><a itemprop="url" role="menuitem" href="features.php"><span itemprop="name">Features</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
```

Now, everything has been fully indexed by google and I am able to see it in *Google Webmaster Tools*.

**So how does Google Webmaster Tools see it?**

```html
Page URL   | Items | Items with errors | Last detected |    Name    | Errors
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Page1.php  |   1   |          -        |     2/11/16   |  Features  |    -
Page2.php  |   1   |          -        |     2/11/16   |  Features  |    -
Page3.php  |   1   |          -        |     2/11/16   |  Features  |    -
Page4.php  |   1   |          -        |     2/11/16   |  Features  |    -
...
```

All my pages which have been indexed and have the menu (Page1.php - Page4.php), each only have **1** item. And the detected item is always only the last link specified in **SiteNavigationElement**.

So there must be an error obviously.

- Why is google only seeing **one** link?
- And why is it always the last link?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct use of schema.org SiteNavigationElement?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12491102/what-is-the-correct-use-of-schema-org-sitenavigationelement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is my original menu structure I came up with after reading all answers in the *duplicate link*

Except my answer, it seems ;-) As I explained in [my answer to the possibly duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22133880/1591669), the `url` property should **not** be used for each navigation link. Instead, the `url` property should provide a URL for the whole navigation (which, typically, doesn’t exist).

The same goes for every other `SiteNavigationElement` property (as of Schema.org [version 2.2](http://schema.org/docs/releases.html#v2.2)), like `name` in your example: it’s for the name of the navigation (e.g., "Navigation"), not for the names of the navigation entries.

So using the [`SiteNavigationElement`](http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement) does not seem to be very useful. The same is the case with [`WebPageElement`](http://schema.org/WebPageElement) and its other sub-types. They [may be useful in special cases and in non-HTML contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27867175/1591669), but generally I wouldn’t use them for typical Web pages.

Comment: So how would I let google know about my menu structure, so it could display a couple of menu links in the search result?

Comment: @lockdoc: As far as Schema.org is concerned, there is no other type for navigations. A related type is [`BreadcrumbList`](http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList), but of course only for breadcrumbs. -- If you mean [Google’s Sitelinks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21238921/1591669): according to Google’s Structured Data documentation, these don’t count as Rich Snippet, so Schema.org is not (at least not directly) relevant for showing them.

Comment: in your original answer you recommend to still use `SiteNavigationElement`, but ommit `name` and `url` property. Would you also recommend this for my case or would you rather recommend to also remove the whole `SiteNavigationElement` ?

Comment: @lockdoc: As I mentioned here in this answer, I would remove it from Web pages (just like any other `WebPageElement` + its sub-types), unless I know a good reason to keep it (which I don’t).

Comment: OK, thanks for the answer. It is very unsatisfying for me, but this is how it is :-(