# How to create google sitemap structure

Tags: seo, sitemap

I want to create google sitemap for my site with structure as image bellow

I has submited xml sitemap to google tools
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google search results site map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225000/google-search-results-site-map)

Answer (score 0):

Google advises webmaster's to build sites with clear navigation and a well-planned hierarchy of pages. These features may make a site more amenable to Google’s Sitelink analysis algorithms but its given based on Google's own algorithm and not a set of defined rules.

Great explanation on how to get them and how they work can be found at:
https://www.hochmanconsultants.com/how-to-get-google-sitelinks/

Good luck and let us know your progress :)

Comment: If this answered your question please mark it as best answer else please feel free to continue the chat :)