# How to feature links on google search

Tags: google-search, robots.txt

I started implementing the robots.txt on a website I'm working on.

Sometimes, I see the feature below when I search something on Google.
[image: Google search feature]

I was wondering if that is something that you can set on robots.txt or on sitemap.xml or it is something that Google it's will do based on your website ranking.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google search results site map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225000/google-search-results-site-map)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called [site-links](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en), and are automatically generated by Google based in its own analysis of your site structure to help users to find popular topics of a website.

[image]

You can only improve your site links to help Google determine if they are worth to include them in SERP as stated here:

> At the moment, sitelinks are automated. We're always working to
>   improve our sitelinks algorithms, and we may incorporate webmaster
>   input in the future. There are best practices you can follow, however,
>   to improve the quality of your sitelinks. For example, for your site's
>   internal links, make sure you use anchor text and alt text that's
>   informative, compact, and avoids repetition.

Comment: Wow, that was a lot faster and way more informative than what I expected. Thanks a lot, man. o7