# I've added Microdata to web page HTML, but it shows up on publishing from CMS

Tags: html, microdata, google-rich-snippets

As explained in searchengineland.com, I've added the following navigation markup but it shows up on publishing the site above the header. I want it to show up like the attached image in Google search results:

> [image: site navigation menu example for search results]

I'm using Sandvox for Mac to publish the site. Where should I add the Microdata HTML?

I tried to put it inside this code and it just prints on the published page:

```html
<div  itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/LocalBusiness" id="sitemenu">
.....
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
<ul itemscope itemtype="http://www.schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
<li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.travelstore.com/our-   advantage">Our Advantage</a></li>
<li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.travelstore.com/our- travel-experts">Travel Experts</a></li>
<li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.travelstore.com/destinations">Destinations</a></li>
<li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.travelstore.com/cruises">Cruises</a></li>
<li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.travelstore.com/interests">Interests</a></li>
<li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.travelstore.com/explore-your-world/interests/hotels-and-resorts">Hotels</a></li>
<li itemprop="name"><a itemprop="url" href="http://www.travelstore.com/travel-guides">Travel Resources</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your screenshot of the Google Search result shows two features:

- a search field that searches the result site
- links to other pages of the site

You **can** provide structured data markup to get the first feature ([Sitelinks Searchbox](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitelinks-searchbox)), you **can’t** provide structured data markup to get the second feature ([sitelinks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21238921/1591669)).

Schema.org’s `SiteNavigationElement` type doesn’t seem to get used by Google Search for any of their result features. I [recommend not to use `SiteNavigationElement`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27867175/1591669) at all.

If you want to use `SiteNavigationElement` anyway, note that you are not using it correctly: [you can only markup the whole navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22133880/1591669), not single navigation links. So the `url` and `name` properties of `SiteNavigationElement` are for the URL and the name of the navigation itself (and a navigation typically doesn’t have these). So it would be:

```html
<ul itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement">
  <li><a href="http://www.travelstore.com/our-advantage">Our Advantage</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.travelstore.com/our-travel-experts">Travel Experts</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.travelstore.com/destinations">Destinations</a></li>
</ul>
```

(Note that Schema.org URIs should be specified without the `www` subdomain.)

Comment: What do you suggest for the second feature without using SiteNavigationElement? How have they done it in the example picture?

Comment: @BUE: Google Search does it on its own. As this feature doesn’t come from markup, discussing it here on SO is off-topic, because it would be subjective SEO advice. It’s on-topic on [webmasters.se]. In the linked answer I linked to the Webmasters SE question: [*What are the most important things I need to do to encourage Google Sitelinks?*](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/503/17633)