# Why Google sitelinks does not work with my WordPress website?

Tags: wordpress, google-search, google-sitelink-searchbox

I have this XML in my WordPress root directory for a few months now:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>https://example.com/</loc>
        <lastmod>2017-08-10</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://example.com/about</loc>
        <lastmod>2017-08-07</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://example.com/portfolio</loc>
        <lastmod>2017-08-07</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://example.com/contact</loc>
        <lastmod>2017-08-07</lastmod>
        <changefreq>monthly</changefreq>
    </url>
</urlset>
```

But it **does not** help on my Google sitelinks at all. I don't see "About", "Portfolio", "Contact" in the Google search result.

Any ideas what else have I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are three different things:

- **Sitemap** (the XML you included)
- **Google Sitelinks** (what you seem to ask about)
- **Google Sitelink Searchbox** (the tag you used)

A sitemap (following the [**sitemaps.org protocol**](https://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html)) is a file that can help search engines and other consumers to find/crawl all your relevant pages.

[**Sitelinks**](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en) are additional links that get displayed with your page’s search result in Google Search. You [can’t do anything specific](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21238921/1591669) to get them.

[**Sitelink Searchbox**](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/sitelinks-searchbox) is the search form that gets displayed with your page’s search result in Google Search, typically together with Sitelinks. You can use structured data (Schema.org’s `SearchAction` type) to power this search form with your site’s own search engine.